# Facebook Application returns 403 when posting to peoples walls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good morning all,

I've got a Facebook application that my customers use as part of our service which with their permission posts content onto their companies page.

It works fine with my account to my company page wall but all my customers are getting an 403 error. I've checked their access tokens and it's not working with much luck.

I've Google around and I'm wondering if my application has been blacklisted or whether it's had a restriction placed on it. We used to utilise offline_access and we didn't realise there was a change to Facebook's policies for a while after this change came into existence. We've since updated our application to require our customers to revalidate their access tokens every month.

Our application is called "Testimonial Monkey" (Id: 155266164542877)

Thanks for your help

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have enough authority to execute an API in / user-id/permissions.
Otherwise you need to get additional permissions for your application.
[a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)

Hope that help

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm asking for publish_stream which is the only permission I need. As I've said (sorry if I wasn't clear) the application can post to another wall of another company which is managed by my own Facebook account. It won't work on any other pages despite getting an Access Token from the owning users Facebook page/account.